# "TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType" when installing Django via pipenv on Windows 10:

Tags: python, django, windows-10, pipenv

I am trying to install Django on my Windows 10 System. Python 3.7.7 and pipenv 2018.11.26 are properly installed. When I try to run `pipenv install django==2.2.5` I get the following error message, for which I just can't figure out the reason:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 
254, in install
    editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1927, in do_install
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1386, in pip_install
    pip_command = [which_pip(allow_global=allow_global), "install"]
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1459, in which_pip
    return which("pip")
  File "C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 117, in which
    if not os.path.exists(p):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

My troubleshooting attempts so far:
I tried to check my PATH variables via `$Env:Path` in the powershell, returning amongst others the following:

```
C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\AMCSPSRICHTERDaniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

could it be that the `;;` is causing the problem, and if yes, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: thanks for the link but I could not find the solution there, maybe you could give me a hint to what the reason for the error is?

Comment: You wanted to edit your path environment variable